# Output operator for class template with variadic template pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, variadic-templates

I tried to write a template class and output operator to it as following:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N
{

template< typename ...types >
struct X
{
    static_assert((sizeof...(types) != 0), "zero length");
    X() = default;
    X(X const &) = default;
    X(X &&) = default;
    template< typename ...args >
    //explicit // does not matter
    X(args &&...) { ; }
    int value = 10;
};

template< typename ...types >
std::ostream &
operator << (std::ostream & out, X< types... > const & x)
{
    return out << x.value;
}

} // namespace N

int main()
{
    using namespace N;
    X< float > /*const*/ x; // `const` does not matter
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But `static_assert`ion raised:

```
main.cpp:9:5: error: static_assert failed "zero length"
    static_assert((sizeof...(types) != 0), "zero length");
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:32:23: note: in instantiation of template class 'N::X<>' requested here
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
                      ^
1 error generated.
```

If class template `X` and `operator <<` overloading defined in global `namespace` then all is the same. I found out, that commenting `using namespace N;` line and substitution `X< float >` to `N::X< float >` solves the problem.

How to explain such behaviour? What is the cause?

**EDIT:**

I find the solution: is to chage template parameters of `operator <<` overloading as follows:

```
template< typename first, typename ...rest >
std::ostream &
operator << (std::ostream & out, X< first, rest... > const & x)
{
    return out << x.value;
}
```

Splitting `typename ..types` of the class is not nessesarily. Moreover, it is not desirable at all, due to extreme bloating of code as consequences.

Comment: using `'\n'` instead of the redundant `std::endl` fixes it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to reproduce your issue:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace N;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

In this case, candidate functions are all overloads of `operator<<` from `namespace std`, all member operator<<'s from `std::ostream`, and your function template `operator<<` from `namespace N`.

13.3.1/7: "where a candidate is a function template, candidate function template specializations are generated using template argument deduction"

So, before overload resolution can begin, `X<types...> const&` has to be deduced from `std::endl`, which is an address of a template function. Address of a function is a function pointer type, and the only way to match `N::X<types...> const&` to a pointer type is to deduce `types...` as an empty list.

(substitution of course fails since there is no implicit conversion from any function pointer type to `N::X<>`, which would have eliminated the overload quietly as non-viable, but the static assert is not in immediate context and is a hard error)

The moral of the story: *using-directives* are evil.

Comment: Good explanation. But deducing `types...` as empty list is not clear enough.

Comment: How `N::X< types... > const &` can be treated as pointer of `decltype(std::endl)` type?

Comment: In the ligh of this answer, substitution `template< typename ...types > struct X` to `template< typename first, typename ...rest > struct X` should solve the problem.

Comment: @Dukales it could be convertible from one. I'll come back to this tomorrow if noone else stops by with further details

Comment: WRT the deduced moral =). Here the using of single variadic pack as template arguments is the evil, but not the using of `using namespace` directive.

Comment: Sadly compilers are right to reject the program because it is unspecified whether a template specialization is instantiated or not during the overload resolution process even for those cases where it is unnecessary (§14.7.1/7). One can [demonstrate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed2c95010b77266c) that the instantiation is unnecessary by leaving `N::X` incomplete. In my opinion the OP was victim of a shortcoming in the language.

Comment: @LucDanton Such rare and subtle details is not necessarily to know in practice. Especially, such as you demonstrated.